# ggplot, scatterplot over an image

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter, ggimage

I'm looking for a way to plot over an image with predefined fields and get a result like this:

[image: Example 1: Result]

**I want to build it from:**

**(1):** a PNG image with the fields with predefined x and y limits like this:

[image: PNG with fields]

and **(2):** a scatterplot, e.g.:

```
mpg %>% 
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy, color = class))
```

[image: Example 2: Scatterplot]

**Question:**
How can I do that, ideally referencing/fixing the fields limits to their x and y values? Regards!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two basic options.

First you could define a custom theme. You might be able to use one of the theming packages. e.g. `ggthemr`.

Second and probably better, add custom curves which would probably require more work initially depending on how curvy. But would be more flexible in the end.
https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_segment.html

Third probably better still `geom_path()` https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_path.html

Fourth use polygons from `ggforce`.
https://luisdva.github.io/rstats/Grouping-points/